# Java homework help, Constructor Mobile Cannot be applied to given types; what does this mean?

Tags: java

UPADTED CODE, however I now get this error message: `illegal static decleration inner class Mobile.mymobile modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declerations, line 73, public static void main(String[] args) {` ,what does this mean??

Help with java homework

this is my assignment that I have, this assignment code I've tried. But when I try to compile it I keep getting errors which I cant seem to find soloutions too:

Error says Constructor Mobile Cannot be applied to given types; required:java.lang,int,java.lang.string; found java.lang.... for Line 44  Mobile samsungPhone = new Mobile("Samsung", "1024", "2", "verizon", "8", "GPS");

Assignment brief

```
To write a simple java classMobile that  models a mobile phone.
Details the information stored about each mobile phone will include
•   Its type e.g.  “Sony ericsson x90” or  “Samsung Galaxy S”;
•   Its screen size in inches;
You may assume that this a whole number from the scale 3 to 5 inclusive.
•   Its memory card capacity in gigabytes
You may assume that this a whole number
•   The name of its present service provider
You may assume this is a single line of text.
•   The type of contract with service provider
You may assume this is a single line of text.
•   Its camera resolution in megapixels;
You should not assume that this a whole number;
•   The percentage of charge left on the phone e.g. a fully charged phone will have a charge of 100.
You may assume that this a whole number
•   Whether the phone has GPS or not.


Your class will have fields corresponding to these attributes .
Start by opening BlueJ, creating a new project called myMobile which has a classMobile and set up the fields that you need,
Next you will need to write a Constructor for the class. Assume that each phone is manufactured by creating an object and specifying its type, its screen size, its memory card capacity, its camera resolution and whether it has GPS or not. Therefore you will need a constructor  that allows you to pass arguments to initialise these five attributes. Other fields should be set to appropriate default values.  You may assume that a new phone comes fully charged.
When the phone is sold to its owner, you will need to set the service provider and type of contract with that provider so you will need mutator methods
•   setProvider ()  - - to set service provider.
•   setContractType - - to set the type of contract
These methods will be used when the phones provider is changed.
You should also write a mutator method ChargeUp () which simulates fully charging the phone.
To obtain information about your mobile object you should  write
•   accessor methods corresponding to four of its fields:
•   getType () – which returns the type of mobile;
•   getProvider () – which returns the present service provider;
•   getContractType () – which returns its type of contract; 
•   getCharge () – which returns its remaining charge.

An accessor method to printDetails () to print, to the terminal window, a report about the phone e.g.
This mobile phone is a sony Erricsson X90 with Service provider BigAl and type of contract PAYG. At present it has 30% of its battery charge remaining.
Check that the new method works correctly by for example,
•   creating a Mobile object and setting its fields;
•   calling printDetails () and t=checking the report corresponds to the details you have just given the mobile;
•   changing the service provider and contract type by calling setprovider () and setContractType ();
•   calling printDetails () and checking the report now prints out the new details.
Challenging excercises
•   write a mutator methodswitchedOnFor ()  =which simulates using the phone for a specified period.  You may assume the phone loses 1% of its charge for each hour that it is switched on .
•   write an accessor method checkcharge () whichg checks the phone remaing charge. If this charge has a value less than 25%, then this method returns a string containg the message Be aware that you will soon need to re-charge your phone, otherwise it returns a string your phone charge is sufficient.
•   Write a method changeProvider () which simulates changing the provider (and presumably also the type of service contract).
Finally you may add up to four additional fields, with appropriate methods, that might be required in a more detailed model.
```

above is my assignment that I have, this assignment code I've tried. But when I try to oompile it I keep getting errors which I cant seem to find soloutions too:

Error says Constructor Mobile Cannot be applied to given types; required:java.lang,int,java.lang.string; found java.lang.... for Line 44  Mobile samsungPhone = new Mobile("Samsung", "1024", "2", "verizon", "8", "GPS");

my code:

```
         /**
 * to write a simple java class Mobile that models a mobile phone.
 * 
 * @author (Lewis Burte-Clarke) 
 * @version (14/10/13)
 */
public class Mobile

{
    // type of phone
    private String phonetype;
    // size of screen in inches
    private int screensize;
    // menory card capacity
    private int  memorycardcapacity;
    // name of present service provider
    private String serviceprovider;
    // type of contract with service provider
    private int typeofcontract;
    // camera resolution in megapixels
    private int cameraresolution;
    // the percentage of charge left on the phone
    private int checkcharge;
    // wether the phone has GPS or not
    private String GPS;
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private int x;

    // The constructor method

    public Mobile(String mobilephonetype, int mobilescreensize,
            int mobilememorycardcapacity,int mobilecameraresolution,String mobileGPS, String newserviceprovider) {
        this.phonetype =  mobilephonetype;
        this.screensize = mobilescreensize;
        this.memorycardcapacity = mobilememorycardcapacity;
        this.cameraresolution = mobilecameraresolution;
        this.GPS = mobileGPS;

        // you do not use this ones during instantiation,you can remove them if you do not need or assign them some  default values 
        //this.serviceprovider = newserviceprovider;
        //this.typeofcontract = 12;
        //this.checkcharge = checkcharge;

       Mobile samsungPhone = new Mobile(
    "Samsung" // String mobilephonetype
,   1024    // int mobilescreensize -- remove quotes
,   2      // int mobilememorycardcapacity -- remove quotes
,   8       // int mobilecameraresolution -- remove quotes, move to the right spot
,   "verizon" // String newserviceprovider -- must be the last one

);
        //typeofcontract = 12;
        //checkcharge = checkcharge;

    }

    // A method to display the state of the object to the screen
    public void displayMobileDetails() {
        System.out.println("phonetype: " + phonetype);
        System.out.println("screensize: " + screensize);
        System.out.println("memorycardcapacity: " + memorycardcapacity);
        System.out.println("cameraresolution: " + cameraresolution);
        System.out.println("GPS: " + GPS);
         System.out.println("serviceprovider: " + serviceprovider);
        System.out.println("typeofcontract: " + typeofcontract);
}


    public static void buildPhones(){
    Mobile Samsung = new Mobile("Samsung", "3.0", "4gb", "8mega pixels",
                "GPS");
        Mobile Blackberry = new Mobile("Blackberry", "3.0", "4gb",
                "8mega pixels", "GPS");
        Samsung.displayMobileDetails();
        Blackberry.displayMobileDetails();
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        buildPhones();
}  

}
```

any answers.replies and help would be greatly appreciated as I really lost!

Answer (score 3):

> Constructor Mobile Cannot be applied to given types; what does this mean?

This means that you are passing objects of a wrong type to your constructor. When the declaration says that a parameter is an `int`, it means that you need to pass an `int`, not a `String` that contains an integer.

The difference between `String` constants and `int` constants is that `String` constants use double-quotes, while `int` constants are not quoted.

```
Mobile samsungPhone = new Mobile(
    "Samsung" // String mobilephonetype
,   "1024"    // int mobilescreensize -- remove quotes
,   "2"       // int mobilememorycardcapacity -- remove quotes
,   "verizon" // String newserviceprovider -- must be the last one
,   "8"       // int mobilecameraresolution -- remove quotes, move to the right spot
,   "GPS"     // String mobileGPS -- must be second before last
);
```

Comment: UPADTED CODE, however I now get this error message: illegal static decleration inner class Mobile.mymobile modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declerations, line 73, public static void main(String[] args) {    ,what does this mean??

Comment: @user2900126 This means that you cannot declare class `mymobile` inside another class.

Comment: does this mean i need to delete public class mymobile { ??

Comment: @user2900126 Either delete it, or move to a separate file if you must have it.

Comment: Ok I have removed the mymobile class from my code but I now get error message: Error says Constructor Mobile Cannot be applied to given types; required:java.lang,int,java.lang.string; found java.lang... for Line 44, Mobile samsungPhone = new Mobile(

Comment: @user2900126 If you understood how/why the first fix worked, you should be able to figure this one out yourself :-)

Answer (score 1):

another issue you are seeing is from this piece here -

```
1024 = screensize;
2 = memorycardcapacity;
8 = resolution;
GPS = gps;
"verizon"=serviceprovider;
```

this is a fundamental java topic. variables.  The variable needs to be on the left side of the assignment operator (`=`) and the value of the variable on the right.

If you are trying to modify the variables of your `samsungPhone` object then you need to do,

```
sumsungPhone.screensize = 1024;
samsungPhone.memorycardcapacity = 2;
etc...
```